# Passing an array of values in an ASP.NET jQuery AJAX POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have a ListBox on my page, and I'd like to make an AJAX post containing all the selected items. Here's my code:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Default.aspx/GetSelectedValues',
        data: '{selectedValues: }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess
    });
});

<select id="lbItems" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to pass in the selected values either as an array, or a comma-delimited string. What's the best way to pass that data, and how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass that as proper JSON, the end result you're looking for is:

```
// Assuming 1, 2, and 4 are selected.
{ selectedValues: ['1', '2', '4'] }
```

However you serialize it, the first step will be to pull the selected values out as an array.  jQuery's .val() makes this easier than you'd expect:

```
// Returns an array of #lbItems' selected values.
var selectedValues = $('#lbItems').val()
```

If you're looking for quick 'n dirty, you can take that and build a JSON array string like this:

```
var json = '{ selectedValues: [' selectedValues.join(',') '] }';
```

Passing that into a .NET JSON endpoint that accepts an array/collection parameter named `selectedValues` (case sensitive) should accomplish what you're after.  You can specify the array/collection as either type int or string, and .NET will handle the type conversion automatically.

If it gets any more complex than that, I'd suggest [using JSON.stringify() to build the JSON instead of doing it by hand](http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/).  Newer browsers implement that natively, but you'll need to include json2.js in older browsers (and it doesn't hurt anything to include that in newer ones; it defers to their native functionality if available).

Answer (score 1):

Is the select element inside a form tag?  You can serialize the entire form and send it through easily.

```
var formdata = $('#formId').serialize();
```

Then in your ajax call

```
data: formdata,
```

--

Recently I dealt with a very similar issue.  I am also using a C# Web Service, but the data I am dealing with is completely dynamic.  I had to find a way to collect a variable length array and pass it as a single JSON string (along with some other fixed variables).  I used the JSON2 library from http://json.org and collected the data by putting a certain class on all desired input fields, and using the title attribute as a key.

```
var formdata = {};
$(".formInputField").each(function() {
    formdata[$(this).attr('title')] = $(this).val();
});

var mydata = JSON.stringify({ 'formdata': JSON.stringify(formdata), 'othervar' : otherVal1, 'othervar2' : otherVal2, 'othervar3' : otherVal3 });
```

Then I passed `mydata` as above.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it in the rest way. a=1&a=2&a=3
You may use jQuery serialize() http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: OK, I'm using that, and that data is being passed as "lbItems=1&lbItems=3". Is there an easy to way deserialize those values into an array in C#?