# How to access rows from multiple tbody in a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, row, cells

I have something like this:

```
<table id="tableId" runat="server">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Example thead1</th>
        <th>Example thead2</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tb0">
    <tr>
        <td>Example 1</td>
        <td>Something</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="tb1">
    <tr>
         <td>Example 2</td>
         <td>Something</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="tb2">
    <tr>
        <td>Example 3</td>
        <td>Something</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I use multiple "tbody" with different IDs so I can delete it or create it anytime I want.

**What I'd like to do is getting each row from multiple "tbody" from the table "tableId".**

In C#, if I use the command "**tableId.Rows[0].Cells[0].InnerHtml**", I get the result: "**Example thead1**".

But if I use "**tableId.Rows[3].Cells[0].InnerHtml**", I can't get the "Example 3" as available in table row, instead of it I get an error which says that row doesn't exist or it's out of index.

Answer (score 0):

Make the tbody elements server controls.

```
<tbody id="tb2" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>Example 3</td>
        <td>Something</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then toggle the visibility as you need:

```
tb2.Visible = true / false;
```

As per comment:

Probably the designer doesn't create a reference to `tb1, tb2, tb3` controls because they are inner controls of `tableId`.
If so:

```
var tb2 = tableId.FindControl("tb2");
tb2.Visible = ...
```

Comment: that didn't work, because when the page loads the tbodys "tb0, tb1, tb2, etc" are not created yet, so I get instantly this error: "CS0103: The name 'tb0' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: when I tried what you said I was trying to save tableId.Rows[1].Cells[0].InnerHtml to a string, and you were right, using the "var tb2 = tableId.FindControl("tb2");
tb2.Visible = ..." made my page load error gone, but I still can't save the tableId.Rows[1].Cells[0].InnerHtml to a string, and I still get this error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: index

Comment: But I also tried to access the only row I can access, which is the first one: tableId.Rows[0].Cells[0].InnerHtml. This time I couldn't save the Example thead1 to a string and I got this error about this line of code "tb0.Visible = true;": Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the your code. and found that **tableId.Rows[3].Cells[0].InnerHtml** will give always **Example 3** ..that's is correct as per your aspx markup code.

i think you have place row index incorrect i.e. something like below

**tableId.Rows[4].Cells[0].InnerHtml** which not exist in your table structure.

that's why you get error of **Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: index**

Hope this will helps you...happy coding...

Comment: I'm still having the same problem, even if I try the tableId.Rows[1].Cells[0].InnerHtml. Only the 1st row is working tableId.Rows[0].Cells[0].InnerHtml..

Answer (score -1):

You could use JQuery, something like this....

```
$('tbody', '#tableid');
```

But I guess depends on what you want to do with them, and where

JQuery docs:

Selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Traversing: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: I didn't understand it.. I'm trying to access the rows by using C#, so I can save it later to a MSSQL DB

Comment: JQuery is client side so if you want results on the server you will need to use a Json call (or something similar). 
Here is a post which covers the basics. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926098/passing-an-array-of-values-in-an-asp-net-jquery-ajax-post
I was just suggesting another way to ‘crack your nut’ ;0)