# Dynamically adding items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, textbox, listbox, postback

I'm trying to dynamically add items which are just strings from a `textbox` to a `listbox` control.

These strings should be able to be added but also be removed. So that's why I came up with the `listbox` control. So i'd need a `textbox` an add `button` and the `listbox` control.

When pressing the submit button, everything in the `listbox` should be posted to an action in the controller.

How can this be done in `mvc 4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the default handling for the submit with jQuery and use .ajax to post the listbox items to your action.

Comment: use jquery's .click method on the add button to copy the textbox value to the listbox.

Comment: And how does everything in the listbox gets posted back to the controller?

Comment: use .ajax to post the listbox items to your action - read this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926098/passing-an-array-of-values-in-an-asp-net-jquery-ajax-post